# Determine if keyframe of Enum Set match in Python

Tags: python, scripting

If the keyframe matches, it appears yellow in the UI, otherwise it appears brown.

[image]

Now, add a keyframe to Data Transfer Modifier (`data_types_verts`)

```
import bpy

bpy.context.scene.frame_current = 1

ob = bpy.context.object

md = ob.modifiers.new(type="DATA_TRANSFER", name="")
md.data_types_verts = {'COLOR_VERTEX', 'BEVEL_WEIGHT_VERT'}
md.keyframe_insert('data_types_verts')

fc = ob.animation_data.action.fcurves.find(f'modifiers["{md.name}"].data_types_verts')
kp = fc.keyframe_points[0]

print(kp.co)
# >>>> <Vector (1.0000, 134283264.0000)>
```

Then, the test function should be:

```
# This time we only consider:
#     frame_current = 1
#     value = {'COLOR_VERTEX', 'BEVEL_WEIGHT_VERT'}

def is_match_of_data_types_verts(fc):
    return fc.keyframe_points[0].co[1] == 134283264.0000
```

However, keyframe point values ​​may not be the same each time.
If you restart blender and perform the same behavior you may find that it is not always equal to `134283264.0000`.
On the other hand, if you use value `{'VGROUP_WEIGHTS', 'COLOR_VERTEX'}`, it is same as `134283264.0000`.

Therefore, my test fails. I'm testing on blender 3.6.

---

###### Keyframe value table (Unexpected results)

```
Value                 | Evaluate  | Binary
-------------------------------------------------------
set()                 | 0         | 0000
{'VGROUP_WEIGHTS'}    | 1         | 0001
{'COLOR_VERTEX'}      | 134283264 |
{'BEVEL_WEIGHT_VERT'} | 8         | 1000

{'VGROUP_WEIGHTS',    | 134283264 |
'COLOR_VERTEX'}

{'COLOR_VERTEX',      | 134283264 |
'BEVEL_WEIGHT_VERT'}

{'VGROUP_WEIGHTS',    | 9         | 1001
'BEVEL_WEIGHT_VERT'}

{'VGROUP_WEIGHTS',    | 134283280 |
'COLOR_VERTEX',
'BEVEL_WEIGHT_VERT'}
```

###### Expected

```
Value                 | Evaluate  | Binary
-------------------------------------------------------
set()                 | 0         | 0000
{'VGROUP_WEIGHTS'}    | 1         | 0001
{'COLOR_VERTEX'}      | 2         | 0010
{'BEVEL_WEIGHT_VERT'} | 8         | 1000

{'VGROUP_WEIGHTS',    | 3         | 0011
'COLOR_VERTEX'}

{'COLOR_VERTEX',      | 10        | 1010
'BEVEL_WEIGHT_VERT'}

{'VGROUP_WEIGHTS',    | 9         | 1001
'BEVEL_WEIGHT_VERT'}

{'VGROUP_WEIGHTS',    | 11        | 1011
'COLOR_VERTEX',
'BEVEL_WEIGHT_VERT'}
```

Comment: Hello, I think you're hitting the floating point data type precision limit. You can't store a number that is both very large and very precise with this data type, you have to choose one of the two.

Comment: @Gorgious I guess it is bugs, see my table I added recently.

Comment: Ok, TBH I think at first you didn't provide enough context to your problem so it's a little hard to know exactly what going on, thanks for the added explanation. It does seem there is a kind of data type precision limit hit here, but I think it's integer rather than float. Just my 2 cents. It does look like a bug, which should be reported to the official bug tracker